# Script to pull ACL on all folders for network drive and list File path, Security Group, users in the security group

Tags: powershell, acl

Script is running to the end point and returns multiple values for a single file path, unsure if this is just how its providing the output for file path or if it is locked into that folder and looping.

Have been unable to successfully filter out Domain users, Admin and other groups listed on all folders to get just the restricted access SGs

Edit, copied the script I had messed with a little trying to get this working, not the most recent somewhat working version updated below.

```
#Start Folder#
$startpoint = "<filepath here>"

#Define function for filepaths#
$Filepath = Get-ChildItem -path $startpoint | Where {$_.PSIsContainer} | select fullname

#Find ACL for each filepath#
ForEach ($Folder in $Filepath) { 
   $ACLObjects =  Get-Acl $folder.fullname
    }

#Pull information from ACLs#
foreach ($acl in $ACLObjects)  {
    $accessEntries = $acl.Access
    $GroupName = [System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]$IdentityReference.Value
    Write-Host "For Folder:" $folder.FullName
    $accessEntries | ForEach-Object {
        Write-Host "Group Name: $($_.IdentityReference.toString().split('\')[1])"
        Write-Host "Access Rights: $($_.AccessControlType) $($_.FileSystemRights)"
        Write-Host "List of Users:"
        Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $_.IdentityReference.toString().split('\')[1] -recursive| Where {$_.identityreference -notin @("BUILTIN\Administrators", "BUILTIN\Users", "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM", "System", "domain users")}| Select-Object Name | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
        Write-Host " "
        
        
    }
    Write-Host " "
}
```

This was the last run, pulls the users from domain user SG, but is stuck on the final folder in the path

Comment: What is inside the variable $ACLs? This variable is not defined in your code. I assume you should use the variable $ACLObjects?

Comment: @guiwhatsthat cheers for pointing this out, realized I copied the one that I had been messing with not the last working version, updated now

Answer (score 0):

Figured this one out, posting in case others need

```
#Start Folder#
$startpoint = "<filepath here>"

#Function for filepaths#
$Filepath = Get-ChildItem -path $startpoint -Directory -recurse | select fullname

#Find ACL for each filepath#
ForEach ($Folder in $Filepath) { 

   $ACLObjects = Get-Acl $folder.fullname
    

#Pull information from ACLs#
foreach ($acl in $ACLObjects)  {
    $accessEntries = $acl.Access
    $GroupName = $IdentityReference.Value
    Write-Host "For Folder:" $folder.FullName
    $accessEntries | ForEach-Object {
    $groupname = $_.IdentityReference.toString().split('\')[1]
        Write-Host "Group Name: $groupname"
        Write-Host "Access Rights: $($_.AccessControlType) $($_.FileSystemRights)"
        Write-Host "List of Users:"
        Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $groupname | Select-Object Name
        Write-Host " "
        Write-Host "----------------------------------------------------------"
        Write-Host " "
        
    }
    Write-Host "
    
    
     "
}
}
Format-list
```